# Change value in jq array on base if condition

Tags: arrays, jq

I would like to ask for help. How can I change value in jq array on base if condition.
My input is ...

```
[
  {
    "main": [
      {
        "drink": "cola",
        "sitem": "10"
      },
      {
        "drink": "pepsi",
        "sitem": "20"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This input I am extending with new items.
My jq call

> jq '.[] | [.main[] | {drink,sitem}] | to_entries | map( (.value.sindex
> = "(1+.key)" ) | .value) | to_entries | map( (.value.status = "10" ) | .value) '

Than is generate new array

```
[
  {
    "drink": "cola",
    "sitem": "10",
    "sindex": "1",
    "status": "10"
  },
  {
    "drink": "pepsi",
    "sitem": "20",
    "sindex": "2",
    "status": "10"
  }
]
```

Change "status" from 10 to 100 where is max value for "sitem"
And I like to expect this...

```
[
  {
    "drink": "cola",
    "sitem": "10",
    "sindex": "1",
    "status": "10"
  },
  {
    "drink": "pepsi",
    "sitem": "20",
    "sindex": "2",
    "status": "100"
  }
]
```

Comment: `.sitem` is a string. Do you mean the maximum after converting it to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get there in two steps: First, compute the max value of all `.sitem` values and store it in a variable, then iterate through all items and change `.status` if its `.sitem` matches the stored max value.

###### Store the max value:

- `max_by` finds the item with the matching condition
- `.sitem` retrieves its value
- `as $max` stores it in a variable

```bash
max_by(.sitem).sitem as $max
```

Note: If you are looking for the numeric max value of `.sitem`, change the condition inside `max_by` from just `.sitem` to `.sitem | tonumber`:

```bash
max_by(.sitem | tonumber).sitem as $max
```

###### Update the matching items:

- `map` iterates through the array with each item in context
- `select` filters for items matching a condition
- `.sitem == $max` is the boolean condition
- `.status = "100"` updates the field

```bash
map(select(.sitem == $max).status = "100")
```

---

You can either append the above to your existing filter, or combine it with the part generating `.status`. For the latter, first store the max value as described above, then (replacing the second `to_entries` from your filter) iterate over the items and generate `.status` on condition, e.g. using an `if` expression:

- `map` iterates through the array with each item in context
- `if` evaluates to either "10" or "100", based on the condition

```
map(.status = if .sitem == $max then "100" else "10" end)
```

Alternatively, you can first simplify both of your `to_entries` expressions by combining them into one, and include the `if` expression into that, e.g. by adding a objects:

```bash
…
| max_by(.sitem).sitem as $max
| to_entries | map(.value + {
    sindex: "\(1+.key)",
    status: (if .value.sitem == $max then "100" else "10" end)
  })
```